# Large Mismatch between Validation and Test Set Performance

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, validation, boosting

I have a time-series dataset, which is split into the following sections:

1. First 50% purely for training
2. Next 40% is for validation, split into 20-folds
3. Last 10% is purely for testing

This is a balanced binary classification problem, and I am using XGBoost.

The problem is that there is a poor correlation between validation performance and test-set performance. For example, Model A has a 56% accuracy on validation sets, and 57% accuracy on test sets. That's good. I wanted to improve the model, so I made Model B. I added some variables, re-tuned the hyperparameters and achieved an accuracy of 58.5% with Model B on the validation set. Then, I see that Model B has an abysmal 46% accuracy on the test set.

Why could this be happening? How could I try to fix this?

Comment: How large is your dataset? If the 10% for testing only consists of a small set of datapoints, then there could be a lot of variability in your performance, which could sometimes lead to big differences from your validation accuracies by chance. In addition, are you randomizing which datapoints get put into training, validation, and testing? If not, could there be structural differences that make the test data fundamentally different from the validation data? If you are already randomizing, try a couple other divisions and see if you still get the same kind of discrepancy in performance.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you replying. My dataset is a total of 1514 points, so 10% is around 150 points that I'm testing on. I am NOT randomizing because as I mentioned, it's a time-series dataset so I thought it makes more sense to keep the time-series structure and not randomize the order.

Comment: @Izzy Just to clarify, the issue isn't even so much that the test-performance is worse than validation performance. It just doesn't seem to be related at all. Model A does good on both, Model B does better on validation but far worse on testing, Model C does worse on validation but reasonably well on test set etc. I'm asking myself what's the point of tuning or variable selection if improvement on validation-set doesn't seem to reflect on the test-set. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: My guess is that there is something fundamentally different, then, about the segment of the time series data being used for testing from the segment being used for validation -- your data may not be as homogeneous as you expect. As a result, a model that performs well on a middle segment of this data may not be a good description of the ending or beginning segment of your data, and vice versa.

Comment: @Izzy I could see that being the case. Are there any solutions to a situation like this? I know this sounds wrong, but could I use the validation set (data closer to the test-set) instead of training set for feature selection and then use it again for hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: @Izzy Nevermind, just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think there is necessary a one-size-fits-all simple fix to this. To me, this would suggest you should investigate your data and try to understand what the fundamental differences are across time. For example, if there is a shift after which data from the past is less or no longer relevant towards predicting what happens to later data, then this may mean it is not appropriate at all to train on earlier parts of the data, or that other training data need to be incorporated somehow. Understanding what's going on may also suggest changes to your model/algorithm.

Comment: There is one more thing that comes to mind to try. If the issue is fundamental heterogeneity over time in your data, then this probably won't help, but otherwise, you could try what is described here: https://community.dataquest.io/t/how-to-split-time-series-data-into-training-and-test-set/4116/2